# Loading content of SVG file to show within ngFor

Tags: angular

I have an `*ngFor` loop that iterates through an array of `layouts`. Each element in `layouts` is a URL to an SVG file.

```
<div *ngFor="let layout of layouts; let i = index;" class="layout" (click)="selectLayout(layout.url)">
    <img src="{{ layout.url }}">
</div>
```

This currently outputs a list of `<img>` tags with the `src` as the URL of the SVG file.

Instead I would prefer to actually inline the SVG file, e.g.

```
<div>
    <svg>blah1</svg>
    <svg>blah2</svg>
    <svg>blah3</svg>
    <svg>blah4</svg>
</div>
```

Is there any way to achieve this? In PHP I would use the `file_get_contents` function to load the content of the URL.

EDIT

For example, my `layouts` array contains ...

```
['assets/images/file-1.svg', 'assets/images/file-2.svg', 'assets/images/file-3.svg', 'assets/images/file-4.svg']
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If I understand correctly, you want to display svgs to style them easily, you could use the opportunity offered by FileReader (https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/FileReader) and have a method in your component, or something higher to read each file and extract its content to display it inside an svg.

But by doing so, you have to make an http call, for each svg you want to show, which can be heavy depending on your list. Is it possible for you to store those svgs locally?

Edit:

If I were to do it, I would create a ts file containing all my svg and a map of all the svg:

```
export const sunSvg = "<svg**>"
export const grassSvg = "<svg**>"

export const svgMaps = {
  sun: { svg: sunSvg},
  grass: { svg: grassSvg}
}
```

I would also create a service that would manage getting the svg content:

```
import { svgMaps } from './svg';

export class SvgElements {
  getSvgElement(element) {
    if (svgMaps[element]) {
      return svgMaps[element].svg;
    } else {
      console.log(`The svg |> ${element} <| does not have a handler.`);
    }
  }
}
```

Then you can call your service through a method in your component to get this content.

Comment: Thank you. I am storing the SVGs locally. I just need a way to show them inline

Comment: Can you update your answer with an extract of how the file where your svg are stored?

Comment: Otherwise explore the options provided by FileReader and renderer2 to insert your svg in the file.

Comment: I added a solution to my answer, if you want to keep separated files, you'll need to use FileReader API!